# Wordpress widget textarea does not allow saving with html tag like <br> and h1, the tags disappear after clicking on save

Tags: wordpress, widget

[Wordpress widget before saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nlWu.png)

[wordpress after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4TW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before saving it into database and use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) before displaying it anywhere.

Comment: i have tried but isnt working, i am working with wordpress the problem occurs after hitting the save button on the widget, by clicking other text will be saved and all html tags disppear..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check in other areas, whether you have used any other html data sanitization or escaping. Did you try using wp_kses_post ? Also take a look at these escaping tag. Surly one of these will work. - https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation